# Не работает копирование текста в буфер обмена на JS

Tags: javascript

Наткнулся на прекрасную библиотеку для копирования текста в буфер обмена на JS https://akuma.su/blog/kak-skopirovat-tekst-v-bufer-obmena-na-js.html

Написал код.
И не работает. Может быть кто-нибудь любезно подскажет почему?
Сразу:

1. `$data["id"]` подставляет правильное значение
2. Файл библиотеки подключен правильно.

   ```
   echo '<textarea id="copy'.$data["id"].'" hidden >Text</textarea>';
   echo '<p>
   <button class="btn btn-info    btn-lg btn_send" id="btn-clipboard'.$data["id"].'" data-clipboard-target="#copy'.$data["id"].'"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
   </p>';
   echo "<script>
   new Clipboard('#btn-clipboard".$data["id"]."'); // Не забываем инициализировать библиотеку на нашей кнопке
   </script>";
   ```

UPDATE: выяснил опытным путём, что работает, если textarea БЕЗ hidden свойства. А вот если hidden -- не работает.Нужно именно с hidden (не обязательно textarea, но hidden).

Comment: Так вы любезно предоставьте место, где можно посмотреть, как и что вы подключили. Телепаты, как обычно, в отпуске.

Comment: Ровно так, как там написано: `<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>`
Вопрос заведомо не в "подключился или нет", я точно вижу, что подключился, вызовы функций отрабатываются.

Comment: UPDATE: выяснил опытным путём, что работает, если textarea БЕЗ hidden свойства. А вот если hidden -- не работает. Нужно именно с hidden (не обязательно textarea, но hidden).

Comment: @Макс Так а что мешает сделать `textarea` видимой, но сместить далеко далеко за пределы экрана? Типа `position: absolute; left: 9999px;` Так будет без аттрибута `hidden`, но в то же время не видел юзеру

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> copyText() {
>     let succeeded;
>
>     try {
>         succeeded = document.execCommand(this.action);
>     }
>     catch (err) {
>         succeeded = false;
>     }
>
>     this.handleResult(succeeded);
> }
> ```

Вероятно, для скрытых объектов выделение с применением <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> не работает.
И код, помещающий `textarea` за пределы экрана, а не прячущий её там не просто так:

> ```
> selectFake() {
>     this.removeFake();
>
>     this.fakeHandler = document.body.addEventListener('click', () => this.removeFake());
>
>     this.fakeElem = document.createElement('textarea');
>     this.fakeElem.style.position = 'absolute';
>     this.fakeElem.style.left = '-9999px';
>     this.fakeElem.style.top = (window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop) + 'px';
>     this.fakeElem.setAttribute('readonly', '');
>     this.fakeElem.value = this.text;
>
>     document.body.appendChild(this.fakeElem);
>
>     this.selectedText = select(this.fakeElem);
>     this.copyText();
> }
> ```